# Which Coxeter Elements have powers that are the longest element of the (Finite, Irreducible) Coxeter Group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, coxeter-groups

Let $(W,S)$ be a finite, irreducible Coxeter Group. I thought it was true (from Humphrey's book Ex 2 on page 82) that if the Coxeter Number of $W$, $h$, is even then $$c^{h/2} = \omega_0 \quad \dagger$$ is true for any Coxeter Element $c$, and $\omega_0$ is the longest element of $W$.

Is this true and have I misunderstood what this exercise is saying?

When I was playing with the $D_5$ Coxeter Group, I found that some, but not all, Coxeter elements have satisfy $\dagger$. Specifically, of all permutations of the 5 generators exactly 2/3s, had their associated Coxeter Element satisfy $\dagger$.

Can someone help point out what my misunderstanding is?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: I believe this is an error in the book. However, it is still true that $c^{h/2}=\omega_0$ if $c$ is a bipartite Coxeter element, meaning there is a bipartition $L\sqcup R$ of the Coxeter diagram such that $c=\left(\prod_{s\in L}s\right)\left(\prod_{s'\in R}s'\right)$.

Comment: @ColinDefant Thanks for clearing this up. Do you know of any sources where I could find out more?

Comment: I just searched a little and found [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54926/longest-element-of-weyl-groups) post, which actually has an answer by Humphreys himself.